# Django 0.0.0.0:80; can't access remotely

Tags: django

I'm trying to access my Django server from another computer on the same network.  I've set up my server and can view everything correctly using`python manage.py runserver` and going to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` but when I try to use `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`, I can't view my Django page from another computer.  The computer hosting the Django server has intranet IP 192.168.1.146.  On my secondary computer, I fire up a browser and try to access `http://192.168.1.146:80` to no avail.  I've also forwarded port 80 (and I've tried 8000 as well) also to no avail :(.  HELP!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I had the same question on a Windows computer, and started the Django server with `python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.146:80`, instead of the 0.0.0.0. (I used a different IP address of course).

After that, a Windows Firewall dialog popped up and asked if I should unblock the port (yes).  Other computers in the LAN could then access the Django server using 192.168.1.146:80.

Comment: Also `settings.py` setting `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` to allow for incoming traffic.

Answer (score 11):

In order for it to work for me, I ran `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` in terminal (Mac OS X 10.8.2), and then in your ipad (or iphone) browser, go to http://[your ip address]/. I *didn't* have to do this: [Testing Django website on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667179/testing-django-website-on-iphone)

[image: To find the IP address on a Mac]

Answer (score 7):

When running it from Ubuntu, it said permission denied when I tried to do this:

```
    python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Since it was a permission issue the following worked just fine like Ryan and gtujan said.

```
    sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

**NOTE:** that you are running a server on port 80, which is a HTTP Port. So when typing the URL from your web-browser you do not necessarily need to type ":80" in your URL.

```
    http://192.168.1.146:80/
```

The following should suffice. Even if you do type ":80" it is considered the same.

```
    http://192.168.1.146/
```

However for other port numbers such as 8000 etc, :8000 is required to be part of the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it is a firewall issue then. Did you make sure to open port 80 on your server computer?

Comment: this indeed was my issue. For linux users you need to allow port 8000 or whatever port you are serving on using command like `sudo ufw allow 8000/tcp`

Comment: @tao Thanks. you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your mention of forwarding port 80, it sounds like your second computer is on a different network (router) from the one running Django. In that case, you should browse to the IP of the Django network's *router* - the 192.168 address is only visible from behind that router, and port forwarding will ensure that your request goes to the right machine.

Answer (score 0):

what OS are you running this on?
have you tried to give the command root privileges? (assuming you're running it on ubuntu/linux)

try running this instead:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ufw allow 8000/tcp
```

You can try this, it also worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried:

```
python3 ./manage.py runserver_plus LAN.LAN.LAN.LAN:8010
```

But can get an HTTP 200 reply without a path:

```
http://LAN.LAN.LAN.LAN:8010/
```

If remote client do a GET request with a path :

```
http://LAN.LAN.LAN.LAN:8010/login


VPN.CLIENT - - [30/Aug/2023 15:31:35] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
VPN.CLIENT - - [30/Aug/2023 15:31:45] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
VPN.CLIENT - - [30/Aug/2023 15:31:48] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I can see the request is reaching the server but client just wait forever for the reply that never came.

The most crazy thing is both server and client can reach each other i.e. ssh works.

Django version 4.2.3

---

**[SOLVED]** telling ovpn server to use TCP instead of UDP

Answer (score -6):

As far as I understand, 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable IP.

It will only work on the local machine, if you bind a socket to the address.

Comment: Actually `0.0.0.0` means every possible IP. It is indeed not routable, but does have this special meaning.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means to bind on all interfaces. So locally it will bind to 127.0.0.1, and it will bind to any interface on any card. Its also a good option if your behind a NAT with the NAT forwarding ports to it, as django wont get confused about why its being addressed with the wrong IP