# Can't access python server started in Windows 7 from another PC

Tags: python, django, windows, tcp, simplehttpserver

I have two computers in the same enterprise network. The one with Windows XP (IP `192.168.101.96`) and the other with Windows 7 (IP `192.168.101.98`).

If I start Django project on PC with Windows XP (`python manage.py runserver 192.168.101.96:8001`), I can easily access it from Windows 7 PC with browser.

But the opposite way doesn't work. If I start Django project on PC with Windows 7, I can't access it from Windows XP PC.

The same situation is with command `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001`.

I tried to add a rule for external connections on TCP port 8001 in Windows firewall settings. Also I tried to add `python.exe` to firewall exceptions, but nothing seems to work...

It should be noted that when I start Django server and execute `NETSTAT -p tcp -ano` command, I can see line:

```
TCP    192.168.101.98:8001    0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6920
```

But nevertheless, nothing work. What can be the source of the problem?

Comment: What happens if you ping the Windows 7 machine from the Windows XP machine?

Comment: "ping 192.168.101.98" works smoothly

Comment: Did you try starting django using the IP address? e.g `python manage.py runserver 192.168.101.98:80` or similar? I think on Windows 7 maybe the IP binding feature isn't working, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901957/django-0-0-0-080-cant-access-remotely

Comment: Yes, I start it exactly as you wrote

Comment: OK, and if you run `netstat` does port 80 show as in use (without Django running)? This would be the case if you have Skype or something else running. I don't know how Django would respond to this. If it doesn't show as in use, once Django is running, do you then see port 80 in the `netstat` output?

Comment: netstat showed me nothing, but I found the source of my problem. The problem was in ESET Endpoint Security special firewall. It's "automatic mode" blocks traffic without any promt to user

Comment: I have ESET, too, and have it set to notify me of any software accessing the internet. It takes a while to start with, but well worth it if you host a lot of server applications.

Answer (score 0):

for access to another computer server , server must be run on port 80.
you must run django server on port 80

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

then access with type ip in the browser without post number :

```
http://192.168.101.98/
```

good luck

Comment: Doesn't work for me. If server must be run on port 80, why can I access Windows XP server started on any port, from Windows 7 machine?

Comment: It seems like port 80 just frees from need to type port number in browser, but it isn't the source of my problem

Comment: 80 is just the default port.  technically, you can access it on any port it is listening on (firewall permitting)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ESET Endpoint Security special firewall. It's "automatic mode" blocks traffic without any promt to user. The problem can be solved by adding special rule to this firewall or changing it's main policy to "interactive mode" for example.