# Can't access Django development server remotely

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901957/django-0-0-0-080-cant-access-remotely) on Stack Overflow, I cannot gain access to the files on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance by running the Django development server. Obviously this server would not be used in production but I want to use it for testing purposes and to check that my Django project is configured correctly.

I tried:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
python manage.py runserver 172.31.19.247:8000 (local IP for EC2 instance)
```

All of these run the development server in the console with no errors. The only problem is, I still can't access it!

**How can I access my Django development server?**

Ideally, I want to be able to access it through the public IP of the EC2 instance.

Comment: You need to use example two I think and access with public ip address

Comment: If you have a fresh install in your install run your server in port 80: `sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: I thought I had a fresh install but I get the error: `Error: That port is already in use.`

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/20174333/3945375

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure port 8000 is added as a Custom TCP Rule into your Security Group list of inbound ports.