# Domain name with local network with Django

Tags: python, django, router

I want test my Django application in local network (wireless). My application is served by a notebook that is connect via ethernet to the router. I already edit (windows 10) hosts file by adding something like this:
`127.0.0.1 mytest.com
192.168.1.8 mytest.com
0.0.0.0 mytest.com`
I start the django server with one of three ip above with `runserver 192.168.1.8:8000` and clearly I add in settings file the `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.8', 'mytest.com', '0.0.0.0']`
the result is that with the notebook I can write in the browser one of the allowed host and I can see the application. If I try to use a smartphone indeed i'm able to view the application only if I type 192.168.1.8:8000. My goal is to digit on the mobile browser mytest.com:8000 and see the application. I use a DHCP configuration but of course I can manually set static ip if I want.

Comment: does your router support custom dns records?

Comment: If i understand you suggest to enter the router config and try to find something to map a local ip with a name "mytest.com"? So if the router not support custom dns records you can't do it? I have D-Link DSL-3782 and a Tp-link archer a5

Comment: I'll add an answer since it is too long for a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need somehow to tell the *smartphone* that mytest.com should be resolved to 192.168.1.8.

Comments on previous attempts:

- hosts file records only affect the computer where it was added. No wonder smartphone didn't resolve the site properly.
- 127.0.0.1 is a loopback interface. If smartphone resolves mytest.com to 127.0.0.1, it will look for this site on itself.
- 0.0.0.0 means "all network interfaces". This would be an invalid DNS record.

Ways to achieve what you want:

- set your desktop IP as a gateway in DHCP settings. Probably even easier than custon DNS
- second easiest option, if your router supports custom DNS records. I cannot give you a specific advise on that but at least some older TPLinks supported that. Just explore the interface looking for something related to DNS in advanced settings.
- If router does not support custom DNS records, you can install OpenWRT/DD-WRT on the router; they definitely support this. This option requires a bit of familiarity with those firmwares.
- install a DNS server on your computer. Then, either directly set this DNS on your smartphone or configure the router to use this local DNS in DHCP announcements.

Don't forget, in all these cases dev server should listen on proper interfaces (settings depend on the development server you're running; see this question for windows: [Django 0.0.0.0:80; can't access remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901957/django-0-0-0-080-cant-access-remotely) )